# Python Dataframe Modification Function Inconsistent?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have these 4 functions that I use to modify a dataframe (without returning anything as per my intention).

The first 3 functions work perfectly fine. The dataframe gets modified according to the function, but the 4th (drop_na) function doesn't seem to work.

It's supposed to drop all rows with NA on the specified column name, but it doesn't work. No error is thrown out when I run the function. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix this (without return if possible).

Thanks!

```
def composite_key(dframe, new_key, key1, key2):
    dframe[new_key] = dframe[key1]+"-"+dframe[key2].astype(str)

def drop_col(dframe, colnames):
    dframe = dframe.drop_duplicates(subset=colnames, keep='first')

def split_column(dframe, arg: list):
    dframe[arg[0]] = dframe[arg[1]].str.split(',', n=-1, expand=True).loc[:, :(len(arg[0])-1)]

def drop_na(dframe, colname):
    dframe = dframe.loc[dframe[colname].notna()]
```

Comment: You need to drop rows with nan value is that it?

Comment: Imho the 2. function also doesn't work. In both, the 2. and the 4., the assignment `dframe = ...` makes `dframe` a _local_ variable.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for dropping na values for a specific column you use this subset

```
df.dropna(subset=['col_name'])
```